# Android OkHTTP set NTCredentials

Tags: android, credentials, okhttp

I want to set Windows NT credentials while calling a Web API. I am using OkHttp. Is it possible to set NT credentials with OkHttp?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built-in. Might be possible to implement yourself as either an `Authenticator` or `Interceptor`.

Comment: Thanks Jesse for the suggestion, will give it a try and let you know.